# How to merge 2D arrays in java?

Tags: java

So I want to merge two 2D Arrays in java, for example:

```
arr1 = {{id, first_name, last_name}, {1, denise, phillips}}  
arr2 = {{gender, ip_address}, {Female, 152.81.244.149}}
```

it would join these and become:

```
arr3 = {{id, first_name, last_name, gender, ip_address}, {1, denise, phillips,Female, 152.81.244.149}}
```

Comment: What is stopping you? What problem are you facing when writing your code?

Comment: I know how to add one into a new array but i am not sure how to add the second one. arraycopy does not work here since I want to merge two arrays and not append them

Comment: Do both arrays have same amount of rows?

Comment: Yes, both have the same amount of rows, different columns though. The new array would have the number columns in both arr1 and arr2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
arr1 = {{id, first_name, last_name}, {1, denise, phillips}}  
arr2 = {{gender, ip_address}, {Female, 152.81.244.149}}
```

and

```
int m = arr1[0].length;
int n= arr2[0].lenght;
String[][] arr3 = new string[2][m+n];
```

another 2D array to store both of them.

Use your data type instead of 'String' here. I used 'String' only to give you the way.

Now to merge `arr1` and `arr2` in `arr3` like as your example:

```
for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
{
    for(int i=0;i<m+n;i++)
    {
        if(i<m)
            arr3[i]=arr1[i];
        else
            arr3[i]=arr2[i%m];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looping over `System.arraycopy` can get the job done:

```
Object[][] arr1 = {{"id", "first_name", "last_name"}, {1, "denise", "phillips"}};
Object[][] arr2 = {{"gender", "ip_address"}, {"Female", "152.81.244.149"}};

Object[][] arr3 = new Object[2][];
for(int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
    arr3[i] = new Object[arr1[i].length + arr2[i].length];
    System.arraycopy(arr1[i], 0, arr3[i], 0);
    System.arraycopy(arr2[i], 0, arr3[i], arr1[i].length);
}
```

This is kind of hacky and gross though - if you have any control over how `arr1` and `arr2` are created and maintained, you should change them there to not have to do stuff like this, which isn't remotely extendable.

The better way would be to create a new class that represents a record, instead of trying to mess with arrays to represent a complex class.

Comment: I don't have control over how they are managed. I am getting data from a csv file and manipulating it.

Answer (score 2):

Since we know that number of rows in each array is the same it means that new array will have same amount of rows. So we can start by making something like

```
String[][] merged = new String[size][]; //where size is number of rows
```

Now we can focus on filling this array with proper rows. To create them we will need to

- iterate over each pair of rows,
- count their columns,
- based on that count create new row array like `String[] row = new String[count];`,
- fill this row with data from both rows.

Last point can be achieved like

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<rowA.length; i++)//rowA represents row from first array
    row[counter++]=rowA[i];
for (int i=0; i<rowB.length; i++)//rowB represents row from second array 
    row[counter++]=rowB[i];
```

Now simply put this row in merged array like

```
merged[rowNumber] = row;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with this, probably not the best solution. Ill try others:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columnIndex - 1; j++) {
        tmpTable[i][j] = tmpLeft[i][j];
    }

    for (int k = columnIndex - 1; k < cols - 1; k++) {
        tmpTable[i][k] = tmpRight[i][k - (columnIndex - 1)];
    }
}
```